# imperfect information in extensive form

Tags: game-theory

Hi I'm trying to understand how to convert into extensive form this imperfect information game.
consider the second graph of this example taken from
[example of imperfect information game in extensive form to convert in normal form](http://www.sfu.ca/%7Eshihenl/302/Strategies%20Memo.pdf)
the game represented in this graph has for p2 the following strategies:

(A;B ->E), (A;B->F), (B;B->E), (B;B->F).

isn't this list wrong and shouldn't it be like this instead?:

(A;C ->E), (A;C->F), (B;D->E), (B;D->F).

(I couldn't post directly the graph because I don't have enough reputation points)

Answer (score 0):

The strategy set is correctly written. It is the strategy set for P1, not P2. P1 cannot condition on whether C or D is played because he does not observe which has been played. Rather, each strategy defines an action at each information set for P1. P1 has two information sets, the beginning and following C or D from P2 -- he doesn't observe which was chosen -- so he has four possible strategies, as listed.

Comment: thanks for answering but I still don't understand this:  Why on (B;D->E), (B;D->F)  B is listed as a strategy itself?

Comment: No problem. (B;D->E) and (B;D->F) are not strategies. (B;B->E) and (B;B->F) are strategies. The letter is on the left hand of the arrow is the contingency. The letter on the right side is the prescribed action. Therefore, you should read (B;B->E) as play B and then, if I play B, then play E. You should read (A;B->E) as play A, but if I play B, then play E. I would usually just write the strategy set more simply as $\{AE,AF,BE,BF\}$, i.e. a prescribed action at each information set, but it's equivalent. Does that help?